# Extending the RestSharp serialization with a custom serializer issue

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I'm trying to improve the default RestSharp serialization by using Json.net library. In order to customize the serialization you have to implement ISerializer interface:

```
public class LowerCaseSerializer : ISerializer{
    public LowerCaseSerializer(){
        ContentType = "application/json";
    }

    public string Serialize(object obj){
         var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings{
            ContractResolver = new LowerCaseResolver()
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, settings);
    }

    string ISerializer.RootElement { get; set; }
    string ISerializer.Namespace { get; set; }
    string ISerializer.DateFormat { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

As you see I'm also extending the ContractResolver. This is the actual code that does the lowercasing:

```
public class LowerCaseResolver : DefaultContractResolver{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName){
        return propertyName.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Once all this is setup I can use it with RestSharp:

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, method);
if (ShouldAddBody(method)){
    request.JsonSerializer = new LowerCaseSerializer();
    request.AddObject(body);
}
var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
```

Everything works, except the properties are not in lower case. When debugging the debuger goes into the Constructor of the serializers, but it's method is never called. When I tried exactly the same for deserializations (IDeserialize interface, which attaches to the client) the method for lower casing was called for each property.

What I have also tried:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;  // no change
// this correctly lower cases the properties
var json = new LowerCaseSerializer().Serialize(body);
// wrong request sent to the server, it tells me that some property is missing
request.AddBody(json);
// the exact same thing with this
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

The thing I noticed with the last two: if I have lower case properties and let RestSharp serializes then the request has 5 parameters (one for each property). If I add it via upper two methods it has only one property and that's the whole json.

I check the RestSharp issues to no avail. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

This very strange:

- forked the RestSharp, installed Json.net, works fine
- copied RestRequest class from RestSharp fork, pasted to my application, used it, works fine
- started new project, installed RestSharp and Json.net via Package manager, works fine

Then removed all packages from my main application, redownloaded, doesn't work. Kinda giving up on this.

**Update 2:**
Debugging through the forked version I noticed this: The RequestFormat has to be Dataformat.Json or it will use Xml serializer. But that doesn't fix the problem. I tried setting both (there are only two) serializers to null:

```
request.JsonSerializer = null;
request.XmlSerializer = null;
```

In the new project I did this causes NullReferrenceException as expected. But in the old one nothing happens. I tried renaming the variables, making another variable of the same type, but nothing fixes is. It just seems that in the project I have the RestRequest class is somehow bugged.

I also added a new project to the solution. And even there the code works. So it's just one project that has the problem.

Comment: Not sure if this is related but when you are adding json to AddBody, wont that get serialized again so you end up with a bad looking body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't reproduce it in a new project, there must be something different going on in this particular project, that's causing the issues, you're describing.

A couple of things you could try (in no particular order):

- Check that you're using the exact same version of the library in both projects (the one that works and the one that doesn't): package version and target platform (net4, net35...).
- Delete the `packages` folder of your non-working project so that NuGet will be forced to re-download all the packages.
- Lookup the exact path to the referenced library in Visual Studio Properties window when you have RestSharp from References node selected. Do a binary compare between the libraries referenced by the working and the non-working project.
- Unfortunately there's no symbol package for RestSharp on [SymbolSource](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet), so you can't directly debug RestSharp in your non-working project. You could use [Reflector.NET VSPro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) if you have the license or haven't used the trial before.
- Move parts of your non-working project to the working one until it stops working.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs) of `RestRequest`, `AddObject` doesn't seem to use the `JsonSerializer` you are setting. Have you tried using `AddBody` instead?

Comment: Package version is the same (104.4.0.0), both projects are using .net4.0, both packages are for .net4.0 (the path to dlls is something like \lib\net4\). This is true for RestSharp and Json.net. I tried deleting the folder, problem remains (also tried reinstalling packages, Update-Package, changing the versions, checked packages.config and they are basically the same). The paths seem fine. I used the diff checker and it says that the files are the same: http://www.diffchecker.com/diff. I will try Reflector and the last suggestion in the afternoon, thanks. I also updated the question a bit.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was using the wrong method. It should have been AddBody all along! The test projected that worked used it and that's why that one worked!